# Map adClick --> appInstallation using Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics

I'm new to Firebase. I've been using Analytics in the past and AdWords as well (on web projects) but never managed to put my hands on Firebase yet.
A customer is asking me to map how many users will be installing his forthcoming app coming from each separate ad he published online, in order to understand which ads are the most profitable ones.

This seems to me to be a fairly normal use case but, believe it or not, I wasn't able to retrieve a proper guide about this topic. In my mind I imagine some kind of console in which I can see for each ad URL or ID the number of clicks and PlayStore/AppStore views and - possibly - how many of those clicks converted to an app installation.

The app will be published on both Android and iOS.

Could anybody help me getting any information about this topic?

Thank you
Marco

Comment: Saw that but the in-page note says "This article describes Analytics SDK functionality. For the most up-to-date mobile app reporting in Analytics, use the Firebase SDK. To learn more, read Get started with app analytics."

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/understanding-attribution-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thank you noogui, this latest link made by day! "Firebase attribution" is what I need! :-D Thank you so much! If you provide it as an answer I'll tag it as the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Firebase Attribution](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/understanding-attribution-in-firebase.html):

> ..a powerful form of app analytics that not only determines which
>   campaigns are bringing you users, but also which campaigns are
>   bringing you valuable users that you care most about.

Also related:

[Attribution](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en)

> It’s important to know which marketing efforts are most effective at
>   acquiring new users and keeping them engaged. The Attribution tab
>   shows how many conversion events were driven by each source and ad
>   network.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this doc to solve your problem from this you can track user movement with page click tracking and event click tracking. Visit the following link to implement it

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Saw that as well but I don't see mentions about tracking from the source page (i.e. an ad container) and the app install. Also, in the first part of the page I read "Note: The Firebase SDK is the recommended method to track Android apps."